# Android Live Edit pauses everytime I change even it's automatic and gives error message

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose, liveedit

I'm using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition. Whenever I change my Kotlin code while the live edit is automatic, it pauses and gives me this message:

```
Compilation Error: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: C:/Users/oguz.temizel/IdeaProjects/Liveeditproject/app/src/main/java/com/example/liveeditproject/MainActivity.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.Function Codegen.generate (Function Codegen.kt:52)
```

I don't know what to do, and I have researched & tried some solutions and didn't work.

Comment: What exact version of IDE do you use? Can you attach your project?

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to Android Studio from IntelliJ Idea and solved my problem.